# Matrix product $C=AX$ - What is $\frac{dC}{dX}$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, jacobian

I haven't found a simple explanation of this anywhere.

I have the following matrix product,

[image] [image]

to give $C$,

[image]

I need to compute $\frac{dC}{dB}$. I handcomputed the jacobian and it looks like this,

[image]

How can I compute the above jacobian in a tensorized way? Is there a nice series of transposes, or matrix multiplications that can result in the above matrix quickly?

Comment: The quantity that you've calculated is $(A\otimes I)$ which is the gradient of $C=BA^T$ with respect to $B$ (after both matrices are vectorized). However, your question is about $C=AB$ whose gradient is $(I\otimes A)$.

Answer (score 1):

[Vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the matrix equation, then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
C &= AB = ABI \cr
{\rm vec}(C) &= (I^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(B) \cr
{\rm vec}(dC) &= (I\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(dB) \cr
\frac{\partial\,{\rm vec}(C)}{\partial\,{\rm vec}(B)} &= (I\otimes A) \cr
}$$
Applying the same process to a slightly different equation yields
$$\eqalign{
F &= BA^T = IBA^T \cr
{\rm vec}(F) &= (A\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(B) \cr
{\rm vec}(dF) &= (A\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(dB) \cr
\frac{\partial\,{\rm vec}(F)}{\partial\,{\rm vec}(B)} &= (A\otimes I) \cr
}$$
which is the gradient that you calculated.